IPV4 & IPV6 suddenly becomes IPV4 only?
I set up an IPV6 on my router years ago. Every once in a great while, my router drops the IPV6 server. I have Spectrum Cable as my ISP. I cold booted both the modem and the router. No luck. My primary DNS server is google. My secondary is cloudflare. I have tried forwarding to different ports as well.My QoS settings are DSCP and WMM both selected. When I log in via my router's status website (both modem, and router are netgear), it shows IPV6 connection status is unavailable.  It is late afternoon to early evening on the 4th of July. My question is: Does network congestion play a role in IPV6 connectivity? If not, do you have any suggestions to alleviate this rare issue?

drops the IPV6 server what server are you running on your router?

No, congestion wouldn't cause IPv6 connectivity to die while IPv4 connectivity is fine. I'd troubleshoot this in stages: 1) Does my router get a valid IPv6 address on its WAN port? 2) Can it ping6 the IPv6 default gateway it's using out its WAN port? 3) Does my router get delegated a valid IPv6 prefix to use on the LAN? 4) Does my router advertise that prefix on the LAN? 5) Do my clients successfully get IPv6 addresses? 6) Do my clients successfully get general IPv6 connectivity to the Internet? It sounds like you're stuck on one of those first 3 steps, but I can't tell which one.
